# Permission for retreiving the tasks in a Plan

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I need to read the tasks in a Plan on a daily batch process. I am retreiving the Plan ID during registration process by delegated permissions and save this ID in the application's database. On the daily batch process I am trying to access this Plan's tasks using;
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans/{Plan ID}/tasks

I am getting "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials" error. I've got the following permissions in the screenshot below, am I missing the required one or is it not possible to access this service with Application type permission?

[Permission List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5WbC.png)

Comment: As per the error, credentials are invalid and it doesnt seem to be permission issue. Were you able to execute any rest call and get results with the same credentials. I tried with same permission as yours and was able to get the results using postman. Can you try postman and see if call to any other endpoint is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application permissions are now supported.

Outdated Reply:

> Application permissions are coming:
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/announcing-updates-to-the-planner-api-in-microsoft-graph/
>
> Before that is live as a workaround to your problem, you can create an
> account to act as a user for the application, and add that to the
> groups you are interested as a member.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it would work for me. As a member of that group, how can I simulate the sign on process? I thought you could only do browser single sign on for delegated permissions. Is there a way to code that login process?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but I don't know the details. I think your best bet is to search for existing questions or ask a new question directly about how to get the token. Describing your environment in more detail would help area experts to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I've made some more research and it looks like there is no way to programmatically getting delegate auth token. For anything to do programmatically, I need application type permission. I will change the working flow to match this. I might ask someone from the team to login to our dashboard on a daily basis to refresh the reports until Application permission is enabled for Planner, hopefully sooner than later.